# "This will be displayed when the device is next switched on" or "It will be displayed when the device is next switched on"

Tags: pronouns, determiners, comparison

> When the device is switched off, the memory will store the mode that last appeared on the screen. **This** (**It**?) will be displayed when the device is next switched on.

Which is better, **this** or **it**, in this sentence? Or are both equally good?

I feel like the pronoun **it** is better because with the determiner (or also pronoun?) **this**, we seem to omit the word "mode" and have to restore it mentally:

> **This mode** will be displayed..

Comment: This may be a matter of opinion, but I feel like **it** is far more fluent and idiomatic here.  **This** isn't *wrong*, but it's just unusual enough that it calls attention to itself.  Like it would make me say to myself, "Why does it say *this*?  As opposed to something else?"

Comment: I agree with @stangdon and would use either “it” or “This mode”.